# Unable to void DocuSign Envelope through REST API

Tags: api, rest, docusignapi

I am trying to void the "In-Process" DocuSign envelope through REST API call. I am using changeStatus method to void the envelope. We are setting the status as "voided" and reason as "voidedReason" in StatusChangeRequest object.

However, after REST API call envelope doesn't get voided. Status remains as "In Progress" in Web-Console.

Any help to resolve this issue?

Thanks,
Shriniwas

Answer (score 1):

I just voided several of my envelopes and had no problems, you must be doing something wrong.  What's the return code when you make the request, are you receiving a 200 or something else?  I suspect one of 4 common problems with your request:

- You are setting the request body wrong.
- You are doing a POST request instead of a PUT request.
- You are PUT-ing to the wrong URI.
- You are trying to void the wrong envelope.

The body for the void request is very simple so let's start with that.  I just voided all of my envelopes with the following request body:

```
{
    "status": "voided",
    "voidedReason": "Void Testing..."
}
```

Next make sure you are doing a **PUT** request and not a POST, as is a common mistake, and also make sure you are **PUT**-ing to the correct URI (following is for DEMO environment):

```
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}
```

Of course, make sure you are using a valid envelopeId that is currently in status "In-Process" and that you check the correct corresponding envelope after the call.  For more information on the void call see [THIS LINK](http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Void%20Envelope.htm).